# How to Remove Duplicate rows in Excel from Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.visible = $true
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Add("D:temp\test.xls")
$ws = $wb.worksheets.item(1)
$Range = $ws.range("J6:J65000")
$Range.Removeduplicates()
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
$xl.workbooks.close()
$xl.application.quit()
```

Comes back with "doesn't contain a method named 'RemoveDuplicates'

All i want to do is delete the row if a duplicate value in `column J` is found.

The data in `column J` is a long string (20 characters) of letters and numbers and some symbols like `"@,=;-"`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It should say `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.` because you don't define `$ws` anywhere. What version of Excel are you using, because I've tested it with Excel 2007 and it can work (using `$ws = $wb.ActiveSheet` and specifying a column number `$Range.RemoveDuplicates(10)`). If you're on Excel 2003 I think the method doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry a typo from my end. I'll add in the $ws definition.
I'm using Excel 2003 but I'm going to try specifying the column number because I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: Okay yes it's basically saying the method doesn't exist. Any ideas of what to try next?

Answer (score 1):

it would be useful for someone, this works for me in office 365 pro plus version 1703 and powershell v5:

```
$path = 'C:\Users\john\Desktop\rows.xlsx'
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Excel.visible = $True
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$Workbook = $excel.Workbooks.open($path)
$WS = $Workbook.WorkSheets.Add()
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item('Sheet1')
$worksheet.activate()
$Range = $Worksheet.Range('A2:G154')
$Range.Copy() | Out-null 
$Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item('Sheet2')
$Range = $Worksheet.Range('A2:G154') 
$Range.PasteSpecial(-4104)
$Range = $Worksheet.Range('A2:G154') 
$Worksheet.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates(1)
$workbook.Save()
$Excel.Quit()
Remove-Variable -Name excel
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$Workbook)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$Worksheet)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$Range)
```

BR!!